# ffmpeg filter dev get_video_buffer function usage

Tags: filter, ffmpeg

I'm writing a mosaic ffmpeg filter.
copy code from vf_vflip.c, I register a callback function get_video_buffer
and implement it as follows:

```
static AVFrame *get_video_buffer(AVFilterLink *link, int w, int h)
{
    MosaicContext *s = link->dst->priv;
    AVFrame *frame;
    int i;
    int j,k;

    frame = ff_get_video_buffer(link->dst->outputs[0], w, h);
    if (!frame)
        return NULL;

    if (s->w == 0 || s->h == 0)
        return frame;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
        // some trick code
    }

    return frame;
}

static const AVFilterPad avfilter_vf_mosaic_inputs[] = {
    {
        .name             = "default",
        .type             = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO,
        //.get_video_buffer = get_video_buffer,
        .filter_frame     = filter_frame,
        .config_props     = config_input,
    },
    { NULL }
};
```

But after read some filter dev guide, I found that only a few filter implement get_video_buffer funcition.The default function is f_default_get_video_buffer()
I make some log find that ffmpeg call function like

```
get_video_buffer
filter_frame
get_video_buffer
filter_frame
get_video_buffer
filter_frame
...
```

I'm confused about get_video_buffer do what job.
Only know that some filter will hold frame cache.
Can I juse comment out the get_video_buffer hook?

I see flip job both in get_video_buffer() and filter_frame() in vf_vflip.c
Is it a waste of time?

```
static AVFrame *get_video_buffer(AVFilterLink *link, int w, int h)
{
    FlipContext *flip = link->dst->priv;
    AVFrame *frame;
    int i;

    frame = ff_get_video_buffer(link->dst->outputs[0], w, h);
    if (!frame)
        return NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
        int vsub = i == 1 || i == 2 ? flip->vsub : 0;
        int height = AV_CEIL_RSHIFT(h, vsub);

        if (frame->data[i]) {
            frame->data[i] += (height - 1) * frame->linesize[i];
            frame->linesize[i] = -frame->linesize[i];
        }
    }

    return frame;
}

static int filter_frame(AVFilterLink *link, AVFrame *frame)
{
    FlipContext *flip = link->dst->priv;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
        int vsub = i == 1 || i == 2 ? flip->vsub : 0;
        int height = AV_CEIL_RSHIFT(link->h, vsub);

        if (frame->data[i]) {
            frame->data[i] += (height - 1) * frame->linesize[i];
            frame->linesize[i] = -frame->linesize[i];
        }
    }

    return ff_filter_frame(link->dst->outputs[0], frame);
}
```

Comment: If the incoming frame isn't writable, a new avframe has to be allocated. vf_vflip happens to have its own calback for doing that.

Comment: You mean 2 implement in get_video_buffer and filter_frame is a MUST?

Comment: why only few filter code like this? Or change frame data in-place SHOULD code as vflip.c ? Others not change frame data in-place?